# keyCode не работает на Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, события

Не работает **keyCode** в **Android** **Chrome**. Мне нужно отловить событие в поле ввода(input) тапа по запятой (",") или точке (".") на Android en, ru раскладка. Использую событие **keyup** в jQuery.
    `$field.on('keyup',function(){`
      `var code = e.which || e.keyCode;`
      `if ( (code == 188 || code == 190 || code == 110 || code == 16 || lastChar == ',') {
   do something;
 }`
    `});`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные пути решения.

Comment: На lastChar == ',' не обращайте внимание.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$field.on('keyup', function() {
  if ($field.val().indexOf(',') > 0) {
    // Есть символ ","
  } else {
    // Нет символа ","
  }
});
```